# Display external video on iMac

Tags: video, imac

I am considering purchasing an iMac. Our office situation is such that the new computer will be placed where a monitor is presently located for a Windows laptop connected via a docking station.

Is it possible to connect external video to an iMac? Alternatively, is the iMac capable of hooking up to a second monitor? (my monitor has multiple inputs which I could just switch between) Are there other options that I am missing?

Comment: Are you asking about using the existing external display with both the iMac and the laptop, or using the iMac's internal display for both itself and the laptop's external display?

Comment: @Dori I'd like to use iMac's internal display.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Console + iMac 27" 2011 External Display](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23418/console-imac-27-2011-external-display)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to connect external video to an iMac?

Yes, the latest 27" iMac can act as a monitor via Mini DisplayPort. From [Apple](http://www.apple.com/imac/specs.html):

> Mini DisplayPort output with support for DVI, VGA, and dual-link DVI (adapters sold separately); **27-inch models also support input from external DisplayPort sources (adapters sold separately)**

You'll need an adapter to convert your laptop output to Mini DisplayPort. Be careful, as some adapters, such as those provided by Apple, are designed to *output* DVI/VGA/etc, and aren't capable of being reversed to accept it as input.

**further reading:** http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3924

Comment: Can i connect a PS3 to the iMac 27 i7 mid 2011?

Comment: @Herr I don't think so, the newest iMacs [can only accept Thunderbolt video input](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/05/03/target-display-mode-missing-in-action-on-new-imacs/), and I don't think there are any adapters yet