# Considering 27" iMac. Can I use it as a TV?

Tags: imac

I may be considering to get the iMac.

I don't own a TV, but I would love to be able to use it as such. I understand it has a DisplayPort input for these types of purposes.

What would I need to get to get my Wii and analogue TV (PAL) hooked up to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to get TV hooked up to a Mac is through a TV Tuner. The best TV Tuners for Mac are by far the EyeTV [tuners](http://www.elgato.com/elgato/int/mainmenu/buy.en.html). The TV tuner could also be used to hook up to your Wii, however that is a bit impractical. Instead consider buying an adapter from RCA to [Mini-Display Port](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3135/display-external-video-on-imac) to use your iMac as a Monitor for the Wii.

Comment: Why do you think TV tuners are *impractical*? They're very simple to use, and most have at least a couple different input options, plus recording software. Additionally, there are *no* mini-DP adapters for TV-centric inputs that I'm aware of. You can find them for DVI, but that's about it. Adapting *from* mini-DP *to* a TV input is possible, but not the other way around. Not only is a TV tuner practical, it's the **only** reasonable option for what Evert wants to do.

Comment: Ahhh. I'm sorry. I typed my answer wrong. I meant I thought it was impractical to simply hook to the Wii. However, that is not entirely true as you pointed out.

Comment: I don't think TV tuners are suitable for gameplay.  They usually introduce a slight delay in outputting the signal, on the order of a second.  This isn't a problem when watching TV, but for playing games it would make it unusable.

Comment: Digital devices, like Xboxes, Playstations, etc., that have HDMI outputs, you could (in theory) run through the Mini-DP.  I haven’t tested that, so I can’t say for sure, and I’m not sure how it would work, if the picture would be letterboxed, or if the display would scale the picture internally.  You just need a Mini DisplayPort to HDMI cable: http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10246&cs_id=1024603&p_id=5995&seq=1&format=2

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that is an input, but only an output, for a second monitor.

Comment: You are correct regarding the new ones. The previous 27" models, the ones without Thunderbolt, could utilize their Mini-DP as an input.